# Network request using asyntask and method order

Tags: android, json

I have a little app that is doing something like the following

- inflating the layout
- getting viewpager from layout
- getting json object from network using asyntask without .get() to avoid blocking UI
- setting viewpager adapter that requires the json object from network and using data from json
- Returning layout

The issue here is that if using asyntask without .get() in some case I get null object and app crashes, most likely due to no json object present yet. I should somehow have the user wait there, and I do use splash screen on pre-execute and hiding on completion of asyntask, but the order there can't be changed, since it's within the viewpager adapter setup. So the execution of the code does not stops there.

With these case, what is the best or proper approach. It seems to me that I can't avoid the UI blocking. Has anyone else had a similar case?

Some pointers would really be great :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in calling `AsyncTask.get()`. I guess you are misusing `AsyncTask`. It only returns that what you are returning in your `doInBackground()` implementation, and here you are returning `null` somehow.

Blocking UI is definetly no option! Forget it!

I would recommend to use well known http libraries like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: You are right, I should not use asyntask for this. Will try volley, based on doc its I believe what I need. Thank you!